# Jquery ou JS puro + CSS3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

O `CSS3` ganhou tantas utilidades que antes só eram possíveis com programação, como por exemplo: Media queries, fb, keyframe, transition etc...

Então, quais são as vantagens, desvantagens e quando devo utilizar?

Comment: Voce poderia editar e melhorar sua pergunta?

Comment: jQuery é JavaScript. Tudo que você faz com jQuery pode ser feito com JS puro, usá-lo ou não vai da experiência e praticidade que cada um quer. E CSS3 não implica conflito entre jQuery ou JS puro, é uma outra ferramenta com outra finalidade e que pode ser usada com ambos.

Comment: As pessoas costumam usar só jQuery para fazer uma animação simples ou coisa do tipo. A minha sugestão é usar CSS3 + trocas de classes com JS puro. Ainda porque só jQuery pesa muito mais. É como alguém que só come em fastfood: mata a fome só que pesa na saúde, digamos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve usa o CSS sempre que possível. O único impedimento que pode/deve ter é por causa de browsers antigos que podem não suportar funcionalidades modernas.

O CSS3 e as suas funcionalidades já fazem parte do software do browser isso quer dizer que intewrpretar CSS é mais rápido de processar, não é preciso ler/fazer parse de JavaScript para fazer um fade in por exemplo, isso é muito util. É mais rápido a renderização e não precisa de fazer download de tantos Kb.

Comment: Você sempre com as melhores respostas :)

Answer (score 1):

Eu considero usar todos.

Por exemplo, em um único arquivo `.js` eu misturo JavaScript puro e jQuery, em outro `.css` me beneficio do controle que posso ter sobre o estilo de cada elemento de uma maneira mais organizada.

Outro exemplo é a criação de animações. Em CSS, animações como fadeOut são menos práticas do que no jQuery. Já quanto a estilização (cores, tamanhos, filtros, etc.), na minha opinião, o CSS é a melhor escolha.

Se tratando de jQuery e JS puro, o primeiro tem a fama de ser mais prático por causa da sua sintaxe simples, mas pra chamada de funções eu sempre opto pelo velho JS, pois me sinto mais confortável usando chamadas de funções como `minhaFuncao()` em qual parte quiser no HTML, seja no `onclick`, `onload`, etc.